# post loop is repeating same post

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, loops, layout

I have my page set up so that it displays 3 posts in a row. And then after 4 columns of posts (12 posts) it shows the **ajax load more button.** The problem is that in my code I originally only had one `col-md-4` but it was just showing one post in a row. So I added two additional `col-md-4`. It now shows 3 posts in a row, but it repeats the same 3 posts in each row. Does anyone have a solution for this?

```html
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // display #ajax wrapper only if we have posts
    echo '<div id="ajax">';

    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    <?php }//end while

    echo '</div>'; // close the #ajax wrapper after the post list

    if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
        load_more_button();
    }


} else { // if there are no posts

    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';

}//end if

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u would like do something like this:

```
echo '<div class="row">';
$i = 0;
while($the_query->have_posts()) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    if($i % 3 == 0){ 
        echo '</div><div class="row">'
    } 
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
     $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: So if I were to put this code into my code above how would it look? Everytime I tried putting everything together I just got a blank page.

Comment: Its pseudocode. If u add a ; at the end of this line "echo '</div><div class="row">'" and wrap the "<div class="col-md-4">" and "</div>" with php echo statements it should be fine.


"Everytime I tried putting everything together I just got a blank page" - you should adjust the error reporting settings, so php prints errors etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not the best at php. The code you provided worked, however the posts are showing up one in a row, not three. How can I make it so it will be three posts in a row?

Comment: if($i % 3 == 0){ 
        echo '</div><div class="row">'
 } , should do this job, idk why is not working for you

Comment: Oh i know why ... i had a mistake in the code: http://pastebin.com/UGVjvcXD

Comment: Awesome, works great. Thank you! There is one more issue if your still willing to help. The load more button doesn't appear (in your first code and second)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132937/discussion-between-mr-void-and-user6738171).

Answer (score 0):

Using next_post() member function of wp_query before the next div display, will advance to the next post.

```html
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel-food');

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1),
    'cat' => 10,
 ));

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    // display #ajax wrapper only if we have posts
    echo '<div id="ajax">';

    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $the_query->next_post(); // advances to next post ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $the_query->next_post(); // advances to next post ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                    <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    <?php }//end while

    echo '</div>'; // close the #ajax wrapper after the post list

    if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
        load_more_button();
    }


} else { // if there are no posts

    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';

}//end if

get_footer();
?>
```